# How to specify a custom settings.xml for Spring Roo in order to avoid regular user_home/.m2/settings.xml.

Tags: maven, spring-roo

Since Spring Roo works with Maven and it picks `settings.xml` from the `.m2` folder in `user_home` path, I am not able to run `perform test` and `perform eclipse` command since my `settings.xml` is configured for some other project. I want to specify my own settings.xml. With simple spring project I used the `-s` to do that in `mvn` command.

How can I achieve the same in Spring Roo?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the answer to your question, however, I advise not relying on those spring roo commands.  Spring roo just delegates to mvn anyway, so you can run the equivalent commands directly in mvn.  I have used spring ROO alot and find that I only use the ROO cli when I am refactoring domain classes..